# Salsa20 stream cipher implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography

I have implemented the Salsa20 stream cipher as an `ICryptoTransform`. It runs fairly fast and has successfully encrypted and decrypted all of my tests. I would mostly like the Salsa20 algorithm to be reviewed (since there are very few reference implementations in C# out there), to make sure I haven't missed anything. I would also like input on my implementation of the `ICryptoTransform` interface.

```
namespace Salsa20Cipher {
public sealed class Salsa20CryptoTransform : ICryptoTransform {
    // The ChaCha20 state 
    private uint[] state;
    private readonly int numRounds;

    // Construct a new Salsa20 state.
    public Salsa20CryptoTransform(byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }
        if (iv == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");
        }
        if (key.Length != 32) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Key length must be 32 bytes. Actual is " + key.Length.ToString()
            );
        }
        if (iv.Length < 8) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Nonce should have 8 bytes. Actual is " + iv.Length.ToString()
            );
        }

        Initialize(key, iv);
        numRounds = 20;
    }



    // Initialize the Salsa state with the given key and nonce. A 32-byte 
    // (256-bit) key is required. The nonce must be at least 8-bytes 
    // (64-bits) long. If it is any larger, only the first 64 bits will be
    // used. 
    private void Initialize(byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        state = new uint[16];

        state[1] = ToUInt32(key, 0);
        state[2] = ToUInt32(key, 4);
        state[3] = ToUInt32(key, 8);
        state[4] = ToUInt32(key, 12);

        byte[] sigma = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("expand 32-byte k");

        byte[] constants = sigma;
        int keyIndex = key.Length - 16;

        state[11] = ToUInt32(key, keyIndex + 0);
        state[12] = ToUInt32(key, keyIndex + 4);
        state[13] = ToUInt32(key, keyIndex + 8);
        state[14] = ToUInt32(key, keyIndex + 12);

        state[0] = ToUInt32(constants, 0);
        state[5] = ToUInt32(constants, 4);
        state[10] = ToUInt32(constants, 8);
        state[15] = ToUInt32(constants, 12);

        state[6] = ToUInt32(iv, 0);
        state[7] = ToUInt32(iv, 4);
        state[8] = 0;
        state[9] = 0;
    }

    // Transforms the specified region of the specified byte array. 
    public byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, 
        int inputOffset, int inputCount) {

        // No parameter checking needed as that is handled in TransformBlock()
        byte[] output = new byte[inputCount];
        TransformBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount, output, 0);

        return output;
    }

    // Encrypt an arbitrary-length plaintext message (inputBuffer), writing the 
    // resulting ciphertext to the outputBuffer. The number of bytes to read 
    // from the input buffer is determined by inputCount.
    public int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, 
        byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset) {

        /* Check the parameters */
        if (inputBuffer == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputBuffer");
        }
        if (inputOffset < 0 || inputOffset >= inputBuffer.Length) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("inputOffset");
        }
        if (inputCount < 0 || 
            (inputOffset + inputCount) > inputBuffer.Length) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("inputCount");
        }
        if (outputBuffer == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("outputBuffer");
        }
        if (outputOffset < 0 || 
            (outputOffset + inputCount) > outputBuffer.Length) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("outputOffset");
        }
        if (state == null) {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
        }

        byte[] output = new byte[64];
        int bytesTransformed = 0;

        while (inputCount > 0) {
            Salsa20Core(output, state);

            state[8] = AddOne(state[8]);
            if (state[8] == 0) {
                /* Stopping at 2^70 bytes per nonce is the 
                 * user's responsibility 
                 */
                state[9] = AddOne(state[9]);
            }

            int blockSize = Math.Min(64, inputCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
                outputBuffer[outputOffset + i] = 
                    (byte) (inputBuffer[inputOffset + i] ^ output[i]);
            }

            bytesTransformed += blockSize;

            inputCount -= 64;
            outputOffset += 64;
            inputOffset += 64;
        }

        return bytesTransformed;
    }

    // The Salsa20 Core Function reads a 64-byte vector x and produces a 64-byte 
    // vector Salsa20(x). This is the basis of the Salsa20 Stream Cipher. 
    private void Salsa20Core(byte[] output, uint[] input) {
        uint[] tmp = (uint[]) input.Clone();

        for (int i = numRounds; i > 0; i -= 2) {
            tmp[4] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[0], tmp[12]), 7);
            tmp[8] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[4], tmp[0]), 9);
            tmp[12] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[8], tmp[4]), 13);
            tmp[0] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[12], tmp[8]), 18);
            tmp[9] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[5], tmp[1]), 7);
            tmp[13] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[9], tmp[5]), 9);
            tmp[1] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[13], tmp[9]), 13);
            tmp[5] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[1], tmp[13]), 18);
            tmp[14] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[10], tmp[6]), 7);
            tmp[2] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[14], tmp[10]), 9);
            tmp[6] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[2], tmp[14]), 13);
            tmp[10] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[6], tmp[2]), 18);
            tmp[3] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[15], tmp[11]), 7);
            tmp[7] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[3], tmp[15]), 9);
            tmp[11] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[7], tmp[3]), 13);
            tmp[15] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[11], tmp[7]), 18);
            tmp[1] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[0], tmp[3]), 7);
            tmp[2] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[1], tmp[0]), 9);
            tmp[3] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[2], tmp[1]), 13);
            tmp[0] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[3], tmp[2]), 18);
            tmp[6] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[5], tmp[4]), 7);
            tmp[7] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[6], tmp[5]), 9);
            tmp[4] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[7], tmp[6]), 13);
            tmp[5] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[4], tmp[7]), 18);
            tmp[11] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[10], tmp[9]), 7);
            tmp[8] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[11], tmp[10]), 9);
            tmp[9] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[8], tmp[11]), 13);
            tmp[10] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[9], tmp[8]), 18);
            tmp[12] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[15], tmp[14]), 7);
            tmp[13] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[12], tmp[15]), 9);
            tmp[14] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[13], tmp[12]), 13);
            tmp[15] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[14], tmp[13]), 18);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            ToBytes(Add(tmp[i], input[i]), output, 4 * i);
        }
    }

    /* Bit Twiddling methods */

    // Serialize the input integer into the output buffer. The input integer 
    // will be split into 4 bytes and put into four sequential places in the 
    // output buffer, starting at the outputOffset. 
    private static void ToBytes(uint input, byte[] output, int outputOffset) {
        unchecked {
            output[outputOffset] = (byte) input;
            output[outputOffset + 1] = (byte) (input >> 8);
            output[outputOffset + 2] = (byte) (input >> 16);
            output[outputOffset + 3] = (byte) (input >> 24);
        }
    }

    private static uint Rotate(uint v, int c) {
        return (v << c) | (v >> (32 - c));
    }

    // Unchecked integer addition. The Salsa spec defines certain operations 
    // to use 32-bit unsigned integer addition modulo 2^32. 
    private static uint Add(uint v, uint w) {
        return unchecked(v + w);
    }

    // Add 1 to the input parameter using unchecked integer addition. The 
    // Salsa spec defines certain operations to use 32-bit unsigned integer 
    // addition modulo 2^32. 
    private static uint AddOne(uint v) {
        return unchecked(v + 1);
    }

    // Convert four bytes of the input buffer into an unsigned 
    // 32-bit integer, beginning at the inputOffset.
    private static uint ToUInt32(byte[] input, int inputOffset) {
        unchecked {
            return (uint) (((input[inputOffset] |
                            (input[inputOffset + 1] << 8)) |
                            (input[inputOffset + 2] << 16)) |
                            (input[inputOffset + 3] << 24));
        }
    }

    /* ICryptoTransform Overrides */

    // Clear and dispose of the internal Salsa state. 
    public void Dispose() {
        if (state != null) {
            Array.Clear(state, 0, state.Length);
        }

        state = null;
    }

    // Determine whether the current transform can be reused (Read-Only) 
    public bool CanReuseTransform {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Determine whether multiple blocks can be transformed (Read-Only) 
    public bool CanTransformMultipleBlocks {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Get the input block size, in bytes (Read-Only) 
    public int InputBlockSize {
        get {
            return 64;
        }
    }

    // Get the output block size, in bytes (Read-Only) 
    public int OutputBlockSize {
        get {
            return 64;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I should mention that the method comments are much better IRL, but I've condensed them here to reduce the line count.

Answer (score 3):

This block of code is insane:

```
        tmp[4] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[0], tmp[12]), 7);
        tmp[8] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[4], tmp[0]), 9);
        tmp[12] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[8], tmp[4]), 13);
        tmp[0] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[12], tmp[8]), 18);
        tmp[9] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[5], tmp[1]), 7);
        tmp[13] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[9], tmp[5]), 9);
        tmp[1] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[13], tmp[9]), 13);
        tmp[5] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[1], tmp[13]), 18);
        tmp[14] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[10], tmp[6]), 7);
        tmp[2] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[14], tmp[10]), 9);
        tmp[6] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[2], tmp[14]), 13);
        tmp[10] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[6], tmp[2]), 18);
        tmp[3] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[15], tmp[11]), 7);
        tmp[7] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[3], tmp[15]), 9);
        tmp[11] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[7], tmp[3]), 13);
        tmp[15] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[11], tmp[7]), 18);
        tmp[1] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[0], tmp[3]), 7);
        tmp[2] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[1], tmp[0]), 9);
        tmp[3] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[2], tmp[1]), 13);
        tmp[0] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[3], tmp[2]), 18);
        tmp[6] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[5], tmp[4]), 7);
        tmp[7] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[6], tmp[5]), 9);
        tmp[4] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[7], tmp[6]), 13);
        tmp[5] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[4], tmp[7]), 18);
        tmp[11] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[10], tmp[9]), 7);
        tmp[8] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[11], tmp[10]), 9);
        tmp[9] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[8], tmp[11]), 13);
        tmp[10] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[9], tmp[8]), 18);
        tmp[12] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[15], tmp[14]), 7);
        tmp[13] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[12], tmp[15]), 9);
        tmp[14] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[13], tmp[12]), 13);
        tmp[15] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[14], tmp[13]), 18);
```

Did you actually type it all out by hand? Work smart, not hard. In pseudocode:

```
for index_quadruple in ( (8, 4, 0, 9), (12, 8, 4, 13) ...) {
     a, b, c, d = index_quadruple
     tmp[a] ^= Rotate(Add(tmp[b], tmp[c]), d);
}
```

And the code is so much shorter while doing the same.

Comment: I agree it is a bit crazy, however it is instantly recognizable by anyone familiar with the [reference implementations in C](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html#speed) or the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#Structure). I felt like trying to condense that block would actually cause more confusion in the long term.

Comment: @scotttyb Now Bill (arbitrary name) arrives, he started programming a month ago. He for wheter reason, thinks he should delete one of those lines. The very slight bug is now undetectable, obscured by so much repeated text. Deleting one quadruple would be easier to spot.

Comment: @Caridorc 1) Does Bill delete the unit tests as well? Even a single test-vector would detect such a change. 2) The OP's code looks pretty slow already, your change reduces performance even more.

Answer (score 2):

First off, note that integrity check is essential with most ciphers, and certainly with stream ciphers such as Salsa20.  Poly1305 is the typical MAC to pair with Salsa20; it is not trivial to implement but you can translate the code of any of the public domain C implementations.

You need to add test vectors to ensure that you implemented the algorithm correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, 
    byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset) {

    ...

    byte[] output = new byte[64];
    int bytesTransformed = 0;

    while (inputCount > 0) {
        Salsa20Core(output, state);

        ...

        int blockSize = Math.Min(64, inputCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
            outputBuffer[outputOffset + i] = 
                (byte) (inputBuffer[inputOffset + i] ^ output[i]);
        }

        bytesTransformed += blockSize;

        inputCount -= 64;
        outputOffset += 64;
        inputOffset += 64;
    }

    return bytesTransformed;
}
```

The name `output` is unhelpful: I think it would be better as `keyStream`. But that's a minor issue. The big issue which I see here is that

```
salsa.TransformBlock(inBuf, 0, 32, outBuf, 0);
salsa.TransformBlock(inBuf, 32, 32, outBuf, 32);
```

won't give the same results as

```
salsa.TransformBlock(inBuf, 0, 64, outBuf, 0);
```

This looks like a showstopper bug to me. I think you need to store unused key stream between invocations of `TransformBlock`.